# Why is benzoic acid a stronger acid than 3-aminobenzoic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds, carbonyl-compounds

Why is benzoic acid a stronger acid than 3-aminobenzoic acid? Obviously at *meta* position, only negative inductive effect will operate. But, how does that make it a weaker acid than benzoic acid?

Answer (score 11):

The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of benzoic acid is $4.2$. The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of aniline (aniline's conjugate acid really) is $4.8$.

The two macroscopic $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$s of 3-aminobenzoic acid (aniline-3-carboxylic acid) are $3.1$ and $4.8$.

When the microscopic $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$s of two groups in a molecule are similar, the macroscopic $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$s are not reflective of one particular group protonating/deprotonating. The neutral form will include both a zwitterionic and an non-zwitterionic form in the case of 3-aminobenzoic acid.

When the groups are close in space within the molecule, there will be electrostatic interaction. If the amino group is protonated, it facilitates deprotonation of the carboxylic acid group. If the carboxylic acid group is deprotonated, it facilitates protonation of the amino group.

**Addition:** There is a very relavent article: [Carbon-13 NMR determination of acid-base tautomerization equilibriums](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00178a024) *J. Org. Chem.*, **1984**, *49* *(4)*, pp 691–696.  It reports that the neutral species is 59% zwitterion and 41% molecular (non-zwitterion).

Answer (score 2):

3-Aminobenzoic acid exists as a zwitterion in solution (just like aminoacids, which the given compound is, just not natural) thus instead of existing as  $\ce{C6H4(COOH)(NH2)}$ it exists as  $\ce{C6H4(COO^-)(NH3+)}$,  thus instead of $\ce{-COOH}$ acting as the acid group, $\ce{-NH_3+}$ acts as the proton donor, and as we know that $\ce{NH_3+}$ is a weaker proton donor than $\ce{COOH}$, we can say that $\ce{C6H4(COOH)(NH2)}$ (3-aminobenzoicacid) is a weaker acid than $\ce{C6H5-(COOH)}$ (Benzoic acid).

Comment: Please don't post the same answer twice. Also for future reference, check the help pages (site guide) and [guides to formatting chemical equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange).