# Why is para-aminobenzoic acid more acidic than ortho-aminobenzoic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds, carbonyl-compounds, amines

> Compare the acidic strength of *o*-, *m*-, *p*-aminobenzoic acids.

I got that *meta* will be the most acidic as it won't be able to show R+ effect of $\ce{NH2}.$

But among the other two, i.e. *ortho* and *para*, shouldn't *ortho* be more acidic as it will cause ortho effect?
But according to my book and the data I [found online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aminobenzoic_acid):

$$
\begin{array}{lc}
\hline
\text{Compound} & \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}\text{(amino)} \\
\hline
\textit{o}\text{-Aminobenzoic acid} & 4.89 \\
\textit{m}\text{-Aminobenzoic acid} & 4.79 \\
\textit{p}\text{-Aminobenzoic acid} & 4.77 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Do you think there may be hydrogen bonding between the amino group and the carboxylic acid?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20493/why-is-benzoic-acid-a-stronger-acid-than-3-aminobenzoic-acid https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/in-aminobenzoic-acid-do-we-have-three-different-pkas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem in *ortho*-aminobenzoic acid is that the acidic hydrogen of carboxylic group is H-bonded with the lone pair of nitrogen in amino group. As a result it is more difficult to extract it compared to that in *para*-aminobenzoic acid since the H-bond must also be broken during acid-base reaction. *Para*-aminobenzoic acid does not have a H-bond due to the distance between the two groups.

[image: H-Bonding in ortho aminobenzoic acid]

I would like to add that since the hydrogen of the $\ce{-COOH}$ group is more acidic and $\ce{N}$ has a lone pair. This is why H-bond occurs with $\ce{-NH2}$ group as electron donor and not the other way round.

Also, I presume that by ortho effect you intended to tell that due to repulsion of $\ce{-NH2}$ group $\ce{-COOH}$ group would go out of the plane. However, as we have seen, it is difficult as it is already H-bonded with the nitrogen atom and moving out of the plane would put strain into the H-bond. Moreover, the repulsion by $\ce{-NH2}$ group is not too intense so it would (in most part) avoid the strain.

Comment: So why is Salicylic acid more acidic than benzoic acid?